# pytube playlist is returning empty array

Tags: python-3.x, playlist, pytube

Recently *pytube* started returning an empty playlist.  What is causing this playlist to be empty?

```
from pytube import Playlist

link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
v=2HtaIvb61Uk&list=PLu8BgVaWowIG_0omesGRkKXK2mqWqAKXU'

print(Playlist(link))

result: []
```

This playlist should return several links. I don't know if it's an update issue, or an error in the code, but if anyone knows how to resolve it, I'd be super grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be another issue in *pytube*, which is likely related to YouTube changing their code. The code below will output the number of items in the playlist.

```
import re
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HtaIvb61Uk&list=PLu8BgVaWowIG_0omesGRkKXK2mqWqAKXU')
playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")
 
print(len(playlist.video_urls))
#output 14
```